# La referencia System.Linq no es resuelta

Tags: c#

Hola tengo un problema y esque en mi aplicacion cuando la compilo siempre me muestra la misma advertencia:

> The primary reference "System.Linq", which is a framework assembly,
>   could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework.
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve this problem, either remove
>   the reference "System.Linq" or retarget your application to a
>   framework version which contains "System.Linq". (MSB3267) - C:\Program
>   Files\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets:1635,5

Intente poniendo xml.linq pero en mi codigo me devuelve errores. Entonces intente usando system.linq pero a pesar de que pongo la version 4.0 me muestra el mismo error. 
el codigo es:

```
byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

            var position = PatternAt(file, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("BLAUMOLAMUCHO"));

            int longitudSeparador = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("BLAUMOLAMUCHO").Length;

            byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[file.Length - position.First() - longitudSeparador];
            Array.Copy(file, position.First() + longitudSeparador, encodedBytes, 0, file.Length - position.First() - longitudSeparador);
    public static IEnumerable<int> PatternAt(byte[] source, byte[] pattern)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
            {
                if (source.Skip(i).Take(pattern.Length).SequenceEqual(pattern))
                {
                    yield return i;
                }
            }
        }
```

Intente compilando con ambos pero ninguno funciono puse la version 4.0 pero sigue mostrando el error que debo hacer?

Comment: Probablemente lo soluciones actualizando tus paquetes Nuget, tal vez antes podrías chequear la versión de la referencia System.Linq, eso puede entregarte alguna información extra

Comment: Primer paso: Intenta restaurando tus nuggets
Segundo Paso: Elimina y agrega las referencias.